# Sending custom UIViewController by Chromecast

Tags: ios, chromecast

I'm trying to get started with Chromecast as well as Airplay, and I'm a bit stuck : is it possible to send directly a UIViewController to the Chromecast-connected device?
From what I looked, it seems I am only able to send basic media (image, text, video) to the device. So, if I understand, the only solution would be to "re-create" the interface by sending the components one by one? (is that even possible? or can you display only one media at once?)

Thanks

Comment: Good luck on sending "UIViewController" to Chromecast!

Comment: I expressed myself the wrong way, sorry. I didn't expect the receiver to understand what a UIViewController is. What I thought is there might be a way to give a UIViewController to the Google Cast iOS framework so the framework would be able to "convert" it somehow to the receiver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create custom channels using HTML5 and you can stream to in-built receiver apps, but no, you cannot send a UIView directly to a Chromecast device

Comment: Okay! But, does the default receiver support more than one media displayed at once? (like, is it possible to have on the screen, for example, two images, one video, and three lines of text, and if possible, each placed wherever I want?)
Thanks for your answer.

Comment: you an have as many images as you want, one video element and as many text lines as you want.

Comment: Thanks! Went through most of https://github.com/googlecast/ projects to see how it works, awesome job M. Naddaf!

Comment: @Paulw11 , i am going to implement cast SDK , my purpose is to share my app screen (not fixed/single screen , user navigates to the screens and i will share those) to a TV or supported screen. Can i do it rather playing and sharing video through SDK ? Please, help me with the workaround.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to use is called "Cast Remote Display". It's currently experimental but shows up in the docs here:

https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/remote

...and there is a sample project here:

https://github.com/googlecast/CastRemoteDisplay-iOS

The sample worked for me without any trouble. Note: you will have to register an app on the cast portal and also register your test device. There was a $5 fee. (There are three types, for this you need to select "Remote Display Receiver") Portal link:

https://cast.google.com/publish/#/applications/new