# How to Cast Custom UIView to Google Chromecast iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, chromecast

I have created a custom UIView which I want to cast to receiver device through chrome cast. However, I am not able to do so.

I am using google remote cast and google cast Framework.

Is it even possible to cast custom UIView through chromecast for iOS ? If yes, would appreciate if you can share some code/references.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible according to this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22501831/sending-custom-uiviewcontroller-by-chromecast).

The suggested alternative solution is to use HTML5. Refer to this [google github samples](https://github.com/googlecast/).

Comment: i am going to implement cast SDK , my purpose is to share my app screen (not a fixed/single screen , user navigates to the screens and i will share those) to a TV or supported screen. Can i do it rather playing and sharing video through SDK ? Please, help me with the workaround.